# Storing long decimal in mysql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am storing a decimal value in a mysql database where the column data type is decimal(12,2).

If I input 10000 then it's fine. But if I want to store 100000 the table is not storing the value.

My code is

```
$query = $this->db->insert('donation', array(
            'donation_ref'      => $unique,
            'user_id'           => $data['donorid'],
            'donation_amt'      => $data['amount'],
            'cause_id'          => $data['causes_i_want_to_support'],
            'countrytospend'    => $data['country_to_spend'],
            'donation_type'     => $data['donation_type'],
            'donation_prompt'   => $data['donate_prompt'],
            'gift_aid'          => $data['total'],
            'donation_date'     => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['donation_date'])),
            'giftaidyesno'      => $ga,
            'donation_method'   => $data['donation_method']
        ));

public function insert($table, array $data)
    {
        ksort($data);
 $fieldNames = implode('`, `', array_keys($data));
    $fieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($data));


        $sth = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (`$fieldNames`) VALUES ($fieldValues)");


        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $sth->bindValue(":$key", $value);
        }

        $sth->execute();
    echo print_r($sth->errorInfo());
    }
```

The debug output is

```
    Insert prepared
Insert executed
object(PDOStatement)#32 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(364) "INSERT INTO donation (`cause_id`, `countrytospend`, `donation_amt`, `donation_date`, `donation_method`, `donation_prompt`, `donation_ref`, `donation_type`, `gift_aid`, `giftaidyesno`, `user_id`) VALUES (:cause_id, :countrytospend, :donation_amt, :donation_date, :donation_method, :donation_prompt, :donation_ref, :donation_type, :gift_aid, :giftaidyesno, :user_id)" }
```

Error handling --

```
public function __construct($type, $host, $databaseName, $username, $password)
    {
        parent::__construct($type.':host='.$host.';dbname='.$databaseName.';charset=utf8', $username, $password);
        $this->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

        if ($this->debug) {
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enable/disable debug for database queries.
     * @param $debug boolean TRUE to enable debug, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function debug($debug)
    {
        $this->debug = $debug;
    }
```

There is no error from mysql end as I can insert the same value manually in the table. But when I am trying to store it via PDO then there is no error and it is not storing the row as well.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You do not even check for mysql errors after executing the insert. This way you can't even know if there was any error...

Comment: @Shadow I have updated the code.But this is not actually generating any error(if there is any).

Comment: Did you configure pdo to throw errors in the 1st place?

Comment: change this $fieldNames = implode('`, `', array_keys($data)); to $fieldNames = implode(', ', array_keys($data));

Comment: also change this : (`$fieldNames`) to ($fieldNames); **Note** use backtick when you're using a keyword or reserved

Comment: @Shadow No. The pdo is not configured.

Comment: @lazy_coder Tried but didn't worked.

Comment: Then you need to configure it, otherwise it is not going to throw any exceptions.

Comment: Are you required to use named parameters in the prepared statement?

Comment: @Shadow Updated the post. Added a debug function and called after execute. No error showing though.

Comment: You ate mixing the 2 error handling mode. The debug call is in the catch block, which will mever run without an exception

Comment: I assume `donation_amt` is the decimal column. I tested your code with PHP 7.1 and MySQL 8.0.1, and I can insert values up to 9999999999.00 without error.

Comment: @BillKarwin Exactly I can insert that range via workbench editor. The problem can be with some other column.

Comment: @Shadow Trying to fix the error handling thing.

Comment: You know you can just use `$sth->execute($data)` and remove your loop calling `bindValue()` for each column? This might not be related to your errors, but just suggesting a way to make the coding a little easier.

Comment: @Shadow Updated the error handling. Now I got the error msg. The problem was with another column that is gift_aid. That column data type is decimal(6,2) but as the amt data is much longer that's why gift_aid column couldn't store the calculated value from donation_amt data which is more than 6. So changed the gift_aid col from 6,2 to 15,2 and worked.

Comment: @BillKarwin  All good. The problem was with another column.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes more efficient than the current way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record:

After several commenters suggested to get accurate error messages from the query execution, the OP discovered that the problem was actually caused by posting a value out of range for a different column than was assumed in the question description.